# SOLR WordDelimiterFilterFactory filter not searching alphanumeric combination

Tags: solr, solr4

I have three content items with given titles:

BASECOAT PROCESS 4 STAGE - 90 LINE

BASECOAT PROCESS 3 STAGE - 90 LINE

BASECOAT PROCESS 2 STAGE - 90 LINE

Now, when i try to search with term `2 STAGE`, solr is giving relevance of content item with title "BASECOAT PROCESS 4 STAGE - 90 LINE" highest.
So it is appearing at the top of list.

Actually as per term the result `BASECOAT PROCESS 2 STAGE - 90 LINE` should appear at the top.

Given below is my field configuration in schema.xml

```
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
      <analyzer type="index">
        <charFilter class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory" mapping="mapping-ISOLatin1Accent.txt"/>
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <!-- in this example, we will only use synonyms at query time
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="index_synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="false"/>
        -->
        <!-- Case insensitive stop word removal.
          add enablePositionIncrements=true in both the index and query
          analyzers to leave a 'gap' for more accurate phrase queries.
        -->
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
                ignoreCase="true"
                words="stopwords.txt"
                enablePositionIncrements="true"
                />
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory"
                protected="protwords.txt"
                generateWordParts="1"
                generateNumberParts="1"
                catenateWords="1"
                catenateNumbers="0"
                catenateAll="1"
                splitOnCaseChange="0"
                preserveOriginal="1"/>
        <filter class="solr.LengthFilterFactory" min="1" max="100" />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="English" protected="protwords.txt"/>
        <filter class="solr.NGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="1" maxGramSize="25" />
        <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="query">
        <charFilter class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory" mapping="mapping-ISOLatin1Accent.txt"/>
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
                ignoreCase="true"
                words="stopwords.txt"
                enablePositionIncrements="true"
                />
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory"
                protected="protwords.txt"
                generateWordParts="1"
                generateNumberParts="1"
                catenateWords="1"
                catenateNumbers="0"
                catenateAll="1"
                splitOnCaseChange="0"
                preserveOriginal="1"/>
        <filter class="solr.LengthFilterFactory" min="1" max="100" />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="English" protected="protwords.txt"/>
        <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
```

It seems that tokenizer is not creating tokens for individual integer values.

```
Protwords.txt => https://pastebin.com/Hwabu2Lk
Solr version => 4.10.2
```

To debug I played around with various values of `WordDelimiterFilterFactory` but didn't got any clue.

Comment: What does the `Analysis` page under Solr's web interface say? It'll tell you exactly how the input and query is processed and show you what tokens are left after each stage.

Comment: @MatsLindh
https://www.evernote.com/shard/s305/sh/a0b6b71e-a919-4362-b619-f93b40646427/4a5629523dcee90d989da8913768d0a9

https://www.evernote.com/shard/s305/sh/eb33e3d4-f675-43ab-af55-ad5eed710c06/cd085a979d61f5ff198752eb3d14a7b6

Field value index and query.